# Getting numbers to automatically move up when inserting lines

Tags: vba, excel

Currently working on an excel sheet to rank projects, we would like it to automatically increase the numbers if we insert a new line and input an existing number rank. If we put in a line and type in 9 for its rank we want the pre existing 9 to move to 10 and the old 10 to move to 11 etc. I have kind of worked it out, however my code automatically numbers the first row as 1 and so forth. This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I As Integer
    I = 1
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For I = 1 To 20
        Range("A" & I).Value = I
    Next
    Range("A21").Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through every cell in column A and, if its value is greater than (or equal to) the one just changed, increment it by one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim v As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target)
    If r Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If r.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    I = 1
    v = r.Value
    If Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), v) > 1 Then ' Only change things if this
                                                     ' value exists elsewhere
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For I = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(I, "A").Address <> r.Address Then
                If IsNumeric(Cells(I, "A").Value) Then ' skip cells that aren't numeric
                    If Cells(I, "A").Value >= v Then
                        Cells(I, "A").Value = Cells(I, "A").Value + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Am I missing something with this code? It doesn't seem to do anything when I implement it and insert a new line and assign a number.

Comment: It will only change something if the number you add into column A already exists elsewhere - for instance, if you type in 9, then any existing 9 will be changed to 10 and any existing 10 will be changed to 11, etc.  But, if there was no other 9 to start with, the 10, 11, etc won't be changed.  If you need it to increment the 10, 11, etc when a 9 is entered but there was no other 9 there (so you will then have no 10 in the column), remove the line saying `If Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), v) > 1 Then` and its corresponding `End If`.

Comment: I understand that, I am attempting to do that, as that is my end goal, but it does not change anything. Even when I have a 9 and enter a new line and put 9 as the value I just end up with two 9's.

Comment: Now I am getting an error for this line `Cells(I, "A").Value = Cells(I, "A").Value + 1`

Comment: @TravisEaston Does your column A contain numbers?  What is the value of `I` when it crashes - look at that row in your sheet and see what the cell in column A contains.

Comment: Now it's back to not even kicking an error back at me. Simply does nothing. @yowE3k

Comment: @TravisEaston The reason it may not be doing anything is that if the `EnableEvents = False` gets executed but the `EnableEvents = True` doesn't, no more events will fire.  Just type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the immediate window and that will start things running again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137794/discussion-between-travis-easton-and-yowe3k).

Comment: This new code kind of works, however it ends up counting by 2 for some reason?

Comment: @TravisEaston - If your original numbers were, for example, 1,2,3,4,6,8,10,12 and then you added a new 3 (perhaps at the end), you should end up with 1,2,4,5,7,9,11,13,3 - i.e. every existing number which is 3 or more should have 1 added to it.  So the only reason I can think of which would cause your numbers to be "counting by 2" would be if they were "counting by 2" prior to adding a new number.

Comment: They aren't counting by 2 prior to inserting a line and adding a number. Anything after the new number ends up counting up by 2 for some reason.

Comment: @TravisEaston - By "counting up by 2" do you mean a number like 5 becomes 7 and 6 becomes 8, or do you mean all your values end up being 2 apart?  (I think you will need to give me a sample of the values before and after, plus tell me the number you are inserting.)

Comment: if i add a line and make that 8, then it goes 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 etc

Comment: @TravisEaston - what were the values that were changed to 9,11,13,15,17,19?  Were they 8,10,12,14,16,18?  If so, that is expected - if your ranking allows "gaps" (as it must if you have 8,10,12,14,16,18) then the code will preserve those gaps.  If you don't have gaps prior to adding a new value, you won't have gaps after adding the new value.

Comment: They were  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15 etc the list goes 1-20 .

Comment: @TravisEaston - Hmmm - I just tried running it with the numbers 1 to 20 as the originals, added in a new number 8, and ended up with my new number 8 and the old 8 to 20 were changed to 9 to 21.

Comment: @TravisEaston - the only part of the code that actually updates anything on the sheet is the line `Cells(I, "A").Value = Cells(I, "A").Value + 1`.  That is simply adding 1 to the current value of the cell, and that line is executed at most once per cell per call of the subroutine.  So I can't see how your cells could be getting incremented by 1,2,3,4,5,6, etc.  (You are using the code exactly as per the answer aren't you?)

Comment: @TravisEaston - and as soon as I posted that comment, I realised what minor change to my code you might have made that would cause **exactly** the results you are seeing - I'll bet you removed (or commented out) the line saying `Application.EnableEvents = False` !!

Comment: I did not. @YowE3K

Comment: @TravisEaston - LOL - I guess my success rate at gambling is unchanged - absolute failure.  If you haven't commented out the line disabling events, I can't understand why the code is executing twice.